# Сайт не адаптируется под Chrome при изменении ширины экрана

Tags: css

Сайт не адаптируется под `Chrome` при изменении ширины экрана. На всех браузерах, кроме `Chrome` это прекрасно работает:

`@media screen and (max-width: .......px){`
 `#div{width: 100%;}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поставьте в `head` такой `meta`-тег:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

Comment: `maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no` - вот такое вот зря. У меня, например, зрение не фонтан :)

Comment: Отметил как верное, но помогла очистка кэша.

Comment: @YozhEzhi но тогда веб-приложение ведет себя практически как нативное.